# Pure CSS parallaxing (not fixed) background for single row in layout

Tags: css, parallax

I'm wondering if it's possible to use only CSS to create a parallax scrolling background that meets the following specifications.

- It works on an element that sits inside an otherwise static layout (i.e. my whole page layout isn't a group of parallaxing items)
- The background isn't entirely fixed in place; it moves, just not as fast as the rest of the page.

I've looked up tons of tutorials for parallaxing backgrounds, and have found some seemingly great tutorials, but they all have one of the following problems.

1. They rely on the [whole page being a parallax group](http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/) so that you're actually scrolling over a container via an "overflow: auto" specification
2. The background is [totally fixed in place](http://callmenick.com/post/simple-parallax-scrolling-effect)
3. [they use JavaScript](http://callmenick.com/post/advanced-parallax-scrolling-effect).

Sooo, I can accomplish what I want with JavaScript fairly easily. Here's a [full working example on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aurLneta/8/) that you can try out.

**CSS**

```
.parallax-row {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-781-324-3.jpg);
  background-size: auto 150%;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
/**
 * Update the parallaxing background img to partially scroll
 */
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
        $('.parallax-row').each(function(index, el) {
            var $el = $(el);
            var fromTop = $el.offset().top + ($el.outerHeight() / 2) - $(window).scrollTop();
            var windowHeight = $(window).height();
            var percent = (fromTop * 100 / windowHeight);

            $el.css('background-position', '0 ' + percent + '%');
        });
    });
});
```

Is it possible to accomplish that same effect with *just* CSS?

Comment: Yes, as long as you can work with Problem #1, as you mentioned before. I think that Keith Clark's method is the only _true_ parallax possible with pure CSS. I recently implemented it for a single section of a page. Everything else that listens for scroll events will have to be rewritten, but it's doable.

Comment: How can your *"pure css parallax"* tutorials have the problem of *"using javascrip"*? Doesn't make any sense. --- As @AndrewMyers already said the first one is the only true pure css parallax I know, that's working great. --- Where is the problem of moving a background-image to a seperate container inside a parallax group?